# Getting Id from Div Class Name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my Html code

```
<div class="span12" id="test" style="width: 810px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="/#tab1" data-toggle="tab">New Stream</a></li>
            <li><a id="addspan" href="/#C" data-toggle="tab">+</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabbable">
            <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    @Html.Partial("_NewStreamPartial",Model)
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var count = 2;
        $('#addspan').click(function () {
            var Id = $('.tab-pane active').attr('id');

          });
    });
</script>
```

I want to get Div Id whoes class name ".tab-pane active"(means i want to get active Div Id) how i can do this?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `dot` to join `classes` in selector

*Change*

```
 var Id = $('.tab-pane active').attr('id');
```

*To*

```
 var Id = $('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this,

```
var Id = $('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
```

You are using [Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) here. but in your dom both classes are in same element. so you have to select by both [classes](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get any HTML Attribute from an element with jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
```

Similarly, you can also get the JS Object Property value using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('.tab-pane.active').prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('.tab-pane active').click(function () {
   var Id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $('#addspan').click(function () {
           alert($('.tab-pane .active').attr('id'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$("#addspan").click(function(){console.log($(this)[0].id);});
```

Comment: Although your answer might be right, please try adding some more explanation to your answer